# Apache Proxy Pass 403 Forbidden

Tags: apache, proxypass

So I trying using ProxyPass have node.js app running on port 3000 to have on port 80/443 too. But ProxyPass giving me Error 403. On my VPS is Apache 2.4.7. I found this solution on internet, so I'm not sure if its right or if is problem in Apache configuration. Also, modules  proxy and proxy_http are enabled.
My 000-default.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName socket.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/stats/
    Options -Indexes
    ErrorDocument 503 /check.html
    <Directory /var/www/socket/>
        Options MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ProxyRequests on
    ProxyPass /check.html !
    ProxyPass / http://stats.example.com:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://stats.example.com:3000/
</VirtualHost>
#This just serve to user index.html where js connect to socket.io using port 3000
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName stats.example.com
    #Redirect / https://stats.example.com/
    DocumentRoot /var/www/stats
    <Directory /var/www/stats/>
        Options MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And here is error that I get in error.log:

```
[Sat Jul 14 22:51:44.269152 2018] [authz_core:error] [pid 5496] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: proxy:http://stats.example.com:3000/
```

Hope I provided all necessary informations.

Comment: The `ProxyRequests on` is not necessary, `ProxyPass` should work without it. Can you try that? https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxyrequests

Comment: I tried it now and without any change, same error in error.log

Comment: "client denied" the client is your Apache.  "by server configuration", the server is whatever responds on port 3000.  Check on that server software.

Comment: Because the host is named `socket.example.com` I have to ask: Is the NodeServer really listening for HTTP connections, or is it a websocket server? In this case you should use `ws://` instead of `http://` and activate `mod_proxy_wstunnel`.

Comment: Is the path you excluded from proxying (`socket.example.com/check.html`) served without that error?

Comment: @Nic3500 I don't know what do you mean with that.

Comment: In this context, is says the client is denied.  The client here is not you (your browser), it is your Apache httpd process.  So this indicates that the refusal is not returned by Apache, but by the application which responds to requests on port 3000.  Are you able to access `http://stats.example.com:3000/` directly?  Does that software have any logs which indicate an access restriction?

Comment: @TobiasK So, check.html is without that error, the file will load properly. The nodejs app is realtime socket as you guess (its socket.io), so i try add ws:// and activate that module, but without any changes, in index.html where user connect to server is still unconected and in browser log is same error - 403. But I think it should be http, because in index.html JS connect to socket using http ('http://socket.example.com:80', 'http://socket.example.com:3000'). The first one give me an error and the second connect properly.

Comment: @Nic3500 Yeah, i can reach that port in browser returning "Cannot GET /". Its right output because Express server running in nodeJS app doesn't listen to get, but only for socket polling (e.g. http://stats.example.com:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MITeC8q)

Comment: I'm running out of ideas, I think I'd need to setup a minimum replica of your system to debug this further. Can you maybe post a minimum version of your socket server code and the Client-JS that connects to it?

Comment: Another thing you can try is add `ProxyPreserveHost On` and proxy to `localhost:3000`/`127.0.0.1:3000` instead of your FQDN if it's running on the same machine. Although it shouldn't matter, it's a thing to try.

Comment: `<Directory /var/www/socket/>` or `<Directory /var/www/stats/>`?

Comment: @TobiasK I appreciate your efforts to help me. Here is index.html https://pastebin.com/J6SnBKaP there you need to edit just variable SERVER_URLS with your url:port, here is index.js https://pastebin.com/1XeW3xpd there you do not need to edit anything I suppose. And I'm using Nodejs v8.11.3.

Comment: @DusanBajic well, the folder stats serve to user just index, thats work with nodejs app, running on port :3000, doesnt matter if its example.com:3000, socket.example.com:3000 or stats.example:3000, its always same app, and the folder socket is for proxy socket.example.com:80 to port :3000, this folder is not important, there is just check.html.

Comment: @TobiasK btw. the solution with the localhost still giving me 403

Comment: Is this Centos7?

Comment: @DusanBajic No, its Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: @TobiasK So as I suppose you give up that. Anyway thanks for all the time you spent helping me.